# Replacing print('', end='\r') statements with logging.info() throws error

Tags: python, logging, printing, flags

Is there a way of passing to the logger a formatted string with an end='\r' flag?
Previously I used to have there a print() statement which I replaced with logging.info() but it stopped working now

```
import logging    
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("Running operation ID: {0} on {1}.    fl-queuetool -z {1} log {0}".format(str(oper_ID), zone))
            while True:
                stat = getOperationStatus(zone, oper_ID)
                logging.info(stat, end='\r')
```

Terminal output:

```
INFO:root:Running operation ID: 6057 on star.    fl-queuetool -z star log 6057
DEBUG:root:_log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'end'
```

Is there a way of fixing it? In the documentations it reads the function accepts *args...

```
logging.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)¶

    Logs a message with level INFO on the root logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().
```

Comment: logs doesn't have option `end` - use `logging.info(stat)`

Comment: it may accept `*args` but later it has to check every element which it gets and use it. It could skip unknow argument but usually functions raise error when they get unknow option - to inform you that there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python >= 3.2, you can set the `terminator` attribute on a `StreamHandler` to determine what the terminator is. It defaults to `\n`, of course. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler).

Comment: What would that look like?  And would it be possible to patch `StreamHandler` to a 
 different `terminator` without affecting all logs?